# How many times do you suffer poison?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, time, poison

Given a poison with no onset, and a frequency of 1/round for 6 rounds, how many times do you take the damage?  Is it "the initial damage, plus damage for 6 rounds" for a total of 7 times, or is it "6 rounds, including the initial damage" for a total of 6 times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### It depends on the poison's type

But assuming we are talking about **Injury** poisons, which say:

> Injury: These poisons are primarily delivered through the attacks of certain creatures and through weapons coated in the toxin. Injury poisons do not usually have an onset time and have a **frequency of 1 round**.

Once, when you take the **initial damage**, and once **again every round**.

Injury [poisons](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/afflictions/poison) (mostly) apply their damage every round for their duration, as described under [Afflictions](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/afflictions/):

> Frequency: This is how often the periodic saving throw must be attempted after the affliction has been contracted (after the onset time, **if the affliction has any**). While some afflictions last until they are cured, others end prematurely, even if the character is not cured through other means. If an affliction ends after a set amount of time, it will be noted in the frequency. For example, a disease with a frequency of “1/day” lasts until cured, but a poison with a frequency of “1/round for 6 rounds” ends after 6 rounds have passed.

Afflictions without a frequency occur only once, immediately upon contraction (or after the onset time if one is listed). Keep in mind that there are poisons with a different frequency, such as [1/minute](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/afflictions/poison/arsenic) or even [1/day](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/afflictions/poison/crones-curse/).

Now, note the bolded area, *"if the affliction has any"*, because...

### Poisons without onset will always cause initial damage

Again, as described under [Afflictions](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/afflictions/):

> Onset: Some afflictions have a variable amount of time before they set in. Creatures that come in contact with an affliction with an **onset time must make a saving throw immediately**. Success means that the affliction is avoided and no further saving throws must be made. Failure means that the creature has contracted the affliction and must begin making additional saves after the onset period has elapsed. T**he affliction’s effect does not occur until after the onset period has elapsed** and then only if further saving throws are failed.

Remember when I bolded *"if the affliction has any"*? Well, here is our case. If the poison has no *Onset*, then it simply *always* deals initial damage when the victim fails their initial saving throw, usually when they take damage from the poisoned weapon/attack. Such is the case of the [Black Adder Venom](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/afflictions/poison/black-adder-venom).

So, to answer your question specifically, it will deal damage (up to) 7 times, once, when the target fail their initial saving throw, and again once per round on it's frequency if the target fails their saving throw for that round.

Comment: From the afflictions page: *Effect: This is the effect that the character suffers each time if he fails his saving throw against the affliction. * This says that they do suffer the for the first failure, if there's no onset time.  This is how they sum it up on the Poisons page in the "how do poisons work" section as well

Comment: I guess this is primarily aimed at your statement that poisons without an onset time don't cause initial damage.  Is that supposed to be WITH an onset time?  It seems to be in contrast with your first part, which says that injury poisons do take initial damage.

Comment: @KyleW Thanks, I had misread and was misrembering how it works. Taking another look at the examples in the book helped clarify it in my head.